# Azure DevOps Get work item notification using API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I want to make a listener that fires an event when any work item gets added/updated/deleted etc.

Current code

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Notification;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi;
using System;

namespace DevOpsApiTest
{
    class Connector
    {
        public void ConnectToDevOps()
        {
            try
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri("https://dev.azure.com/Org");
                VssCredentials creds = new VssBasicCredential("Username", "Password");
                VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(uri, creds);

                WorkItemTrackingHttpClient witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
                WorkItem workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync("TestProject", 1).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to make a listener that fires an event when I add/update/delete work item on the DevOps project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize a [service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops)

> Service hook publishers define a set of events. Subscriptions listen
> for the events and define actions to take based on the event.
> Subscriptions also target consumers, which are external services that
> can run their own actions, when an event occurs.

You can start looking into [web hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops), which is easy to get started with, provided that you can publish your piece of code above on a publicly accessible url

> Webhooks provide a way to send a JSON representation of an event to
> any service. All that is required is a public endpoint (HTTP or
> HTTPS).

The  is configured in your project settings and you can configure three of them to fire events on [`work item created`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#workitem.created), [`work item updated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#workitem.updated) and [`work item deleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops#workitem.deleted) respectively.

The web hook sends a HTTP request to the endpoint you specify with a [json payload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?view=azure-devops) containing information about the event. You would have to modify your code to act as a server accepting those requests instead of being a client.